# Counting Special character 2 time and other character 1 time

Tags: javascript

I want to put a counter on textarea to count special character two times, and other characters 1 time after key stroke.

This is the code that i have done so far:

```js
function count_up(obj) {

  var count = obj.value.length;
  document.getElementById('count1').innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Count Up</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" onkeyup="count_up(this);" maxlength="20"></textarea>
    <span class="text-muted pull-right" id="count1">0</span>
  </div>
  <br><br>

</form>
```

Comment: So what's the question

Comment: By "Special character", you mean non-alphanumeric?

Comment: The counter should add special character 2 times and alpahnumeric 1 time after every keystroke.

Comment: yes @Snowmonkey.

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: by mistake, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the number of special characters with the number of non-special.

Something like this:

```js
function count_up(obj) {

  //Matches characters that are not A-Z or 0-9
  var countSpecial = (obj.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g) || [] ).length * 2;
  //Matches characters that are A-Z or 0-9 (because of the ^ symbol)
  var count = (obj.value.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g) || [] ).length;
  document.getElementById('count1').innerHTML = count + countSpecial;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Count Up</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" onkeyup="count_up(this);" maxlength="20"></textarea>
    <span class="text-muted pull-right" id="count1">0</span>
  </div>
  <br><br>

</form>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is performatic as my knowledge of regex is real low

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could simply count the alphanumeric, and subtract that from the total -- its never really stipulated that you need the actual string, simply the count.

```js
document.querySelector("#count-this").addEventListener("keyup", count_up);

function count_up(evt) {
  var obj = evt.target;
  var text = obj.value;
  var alphaNumeric = text.replace(/[\W_]+/gmi, "");
  var specialCount = text.length - alphaNumeric.length;
  var count = alphaNumeric.length;
  // console.log(text + ", " + alphaNumeric);
  document.querySelector('.alphanumeric-count .counter').innerHTML = count;
  document.querySelector('.non-alphanumeric-count .counter').innerHTML = specialCount;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Count Up</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="count-this" maxlength="20"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <div class="alphanumeric-count">
      Alphanumeric: <span class="text-muted pull-right counter" >0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="non-alphanumeric-count">
      Special: <span class="text-muted pull-right counter" >0</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Or if you prefer, here it is **[as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/8m1m26qt/)**.